# Get submenu popup window when opened?

Tags: wpf

I have a tree of `MenuItem`'s in my xaml and I need to get hold of the separate visual tree when a new level is opened. I'm subscribing to the event `MenuItem.SubmenuOpenedEvent` but this will only give me a reference to the particular `MenuItem` that has been clicked. I need a reference to the new visual tree root as well. Any suggestions?

Any way of getting hold of new visual trees when they are created anywhere in the application would be great.

I have tried extracting all kinds of private members such as `MenuItem._submenuPopup` and `Application.NonAppWindowsInternal` but they all turn out to be null/empty. No luck there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SubmenuOpenedEvent` is a bit of a misnomer, because at the time it is raised, the submenu hasn't *actually* been loaded into a visual tree.  Thus, it hasn't actually 'opened' in the most meaningful sense of the word.

To be notified when the submenu *has* been opened, you can subscribe to `MenuItem.Loaded`.  You could do this ahead of time, but I'd probably do it on demand when `SubmenuOpenedEvent` is raised:

```
private void OnMenuItemSubmenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;

    var anyChild = menuItem.Items.OfType<FrameworkElement>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (anyChild != null)
    {
        var handler = default(RoutedEventHandler);

        handler = (o, args) =>
                  {
                      anyChild.Loaded -= handler;

                      var popup = anyChild?.FindPopup();

                      // Do something with the Popup.
                  };

        anyChild.Loaded += handler;
    }
}
```

`FindPopup` is a utility extension method, as defined below:

```
public static class UIHelpers
{
    public static Popup FindPopup(this DependencyObject popupDescendant)
    {
        if (popupDescendant == null)
            return null;

        var popupRoot = popupDescendant.FindVisualRoot() ??
                        popupDescendant;

        return popupRoot.GetLogicalParent() as Popup;
    }

    public static DependencyObject FindVisualRoot(this DependencyObject sourceElement)
    {
        var currentElement = sourceElement;

        while (currentElement != null)
        {
            var parent = currentElement.GetVisualParent();
            if (parent == null)
                return currentElement;

            currentElement = parent;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static DependencyObject GetVisualParent(this DependencyObject sourceElement)
    {
        if (sourceElement == null)
            return null;

        if (sourceElement is Visual || sourceElement is Visual3D)
            return VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sourceElement);

        var contentElement = sourceElement as ContentElement;
        if (contentElement != null)
            return ContentOperations.GetParent(contentElement);

        return null;
    }

    public static DependencyObject GetLogicalParent(this DependencyObject sourceElement)
    {
        if (sourceElement == null)
            return null;

        var logicalParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(sourceElement);
        if (logicalParent != null)
            return logicalParent;

        var frameworkElement = sourceElement as FrameworkElement;
        if (frameworkElement != null)
            return frameworkElement.TemplatedParent;

        return (sourceElement as FrameworkContentElement)?.TemplatedParent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, thanks! But getting the Popup wasn't what I wanted it turned out. It didn't have any visual children (what I wanted in the next step). But just getting the visual root was enough.

Comment: `Popup` doesn't have a visual child: it has a logical child, and that child is the `PopupRoot` (an internal class).  The popup's content is a visual child of the popup root.